# Spring-Security x509 X509PrincipalExtractor

Tags: spring-security, x509

I am trying to get a Spring security configuration working but am have some problems and I am not sure what to do.  I have successfully used x509 with the following configuration

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="rrportalUserDetailsService" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/selfRegistration/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:port-mappings>
      <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>
</security:http>
```

The problem is that the CN of the certificate is not good enough for me to properly authorize and assign my roles.  I need to parse some items out of extensions of the X509Certificate. I think a X509PrincipalExtractor is perfect for what I need, but I cannot figure out how to wire it up properly.

I have this, but I am not sure what I need as far as AuthenticationEntrypoint. Can I not just implement my own extraction and pass a custom string to my UserDetailsService?

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="????" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/selfRegistration/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="http"/>
    <security:port-mappings>
      <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>
    <security:custom-filter position="X509_FILTER" ref="myX509AuthenticationFilter" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="rrportalUserDetailsService">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="myX509AuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
  <property name="principalExtractor">
     <bean class="com.ctc.rrportal.security.rrportalX509PrincipalExtractor" />
  </property></bean>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction or point me to a sample configuration I would be very grateful.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom AuthenticationProvider in your authentication provider. While implementing authenticate method, you can extract any additional information from Authentication object, which should be instance of PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken, and process it as you need. Thus, you do not need custom principal extractor. DaoAuthenticationProvider by default supports only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. The other way is to subclass it and implement support for both authentication tokens.

```
public class X509AuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String CN_PATTERN = "CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)";
    private static final String OU_PATTERN = "OU=(.*?)(?:,|$)";

    private Pattern cnPattern = Pattern.compile(CN_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private Pattern ouPattern = Pattern.compile(OU_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public X509AuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService, "UserDetailsService should be provided");
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String credentials = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Matcher matcher = cnPattern.matcher(credentials);

        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("CN not found in subject DN: {0}", credentials));
        }
        String username = matcher.group(1);

        matcher = ouPattern.matcher(credentials);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("OU not found in subject DN: {0}", credentials));
        }
        username = matcher.group(1) + "\\" + username;

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authentication.getCredentials(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the X509PrincipalExtractor not the proper object to create in this instance? It seems like building the extractor is the "more correct" way of doing this? Is that not true?